# Laravel 5.2 confusing the route

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have two laravel routes

```
Route::get('/chefpage/{chefid}', 'HomeController@fetchchefdata');
```

which redirects to a page containing a form

```
    <div class="form-group" method="POST" action="/addreview">
```

and the respective route

```
 Route::post('/addreview', 'HomeController@addreview');
```

When I post the form, rather than calling the later route, it appends the data like a GET request in the url and I guess it keeps calling the first route instead.

Comment: A `<div>` tag is not a `<form>` tag...

Answer (score 0):

You need an opening and closing form tag.  Try something like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <form action="/addreview" method="POST">
        <!--   contents of your form here   -->
    </form>
</div>
```